# Vue.js: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, webpack

I'm using a single file component style Vue.js backed by a .NET 4.5 server.

Here is my app.js (entry point):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import home from './components/home.vue';
import Quasar from 'quasar';
Vue.use(Quasar);

// Import CSS from 'quasar.css';
import 'quasar/dist/quasar.css';

const application = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(home)
});
```

Here is my home.vue:

```
<template>

    <div>

        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <q-input outlined label="Input 1" v-model="text" />
        <q-input outlined label="Input 2" placeholder="I am a Quasar input element" v-model="text2" />

        <div>{{ text }} </div>
        <div>{{ text2 }} </div>

    </div>

</template>

<script>

    import QInput from 'quasar';
    import patient from './patient.vue';
        export default {

            data() {

                return {

                    text: ''
                    , text2: ''
                    , title: "Welcome!"
                }
            },
            methods: {

            },
            components: {
                'patient': patient,
                'q-input' : QInput
            }
        }

</script>
```

The 'patient' vue is never rendered, so I will leave it out for now. If you believe it is relevant please let me know and I can include it.

I have a layout and a home index file constructed server side. The HTML resulting looks like this:

[image: Vue App Elements]

Now, its failing as such:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at bodyInit (body.js:52)
    at Object.install (body.js:86)
    at Object.eval [as install] (install.js:39)
    at Object.install (index.esm.js:327)
    at Function.Vue.use (vue.runtime.esm.js:5091)
    at eval (webpack:///./App_Client/app.js?:13)
    at Module../App_Client/app.js (client-app.js:97)
    at __webpack_require__ (client-app.js:20)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_./App_Client/app.js?:1)
    at Object.0 (client-app.js:3689)
```

In body.js, it fails here:

```
document.body.classList.add.apply(document.body.classList, cls)
```

I know there are some similar questions, but generally people are trying to do things like GetElementById(); on elements that don't exist. My body clearly exists, both in code and in the elements view. I am using webpack. I'm a bit confused as to where this error is coming from.

Comment: Could you confirm that this error is in the browser console, not something on the server such as server-side rendering? Assuming it is client-side, my first thought would be to take a look at the HTML file and check you aren't including the `<script>` before the `<body>`. The picture makes me think you've got the `<script>` in the `<head>`, which would be before `<body>` exists. If you pause in the debugger when the error occurs you should be able to poke around to figure out exactly what's going on.

Comment: @skirtle Wow, that was it, I feel very foolish. In other frameworks (angularjs, jquery) these javascript bindings happen on document.ready() which is always after the DOM loads. I'm very new at vue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue.js doesn't internally use jQuery so it doesn't not wait for $( document ).ready() like some other libraries do. You can move script tags to the bottom of your HTML, or, alternatively you can wrap your entry point in a listener for the DOMContentLoaded event like so:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function (event) {

     new Vue({

        el: '#app'
        , render: h => h(App)
        , created() {

        }
    });
});
```